# Test if hash include any element

Tags: ruby, hash, rspec

I am testing with Rspec, and I would like to check if an array contain some element from another array.

```
elements = ['e1', 'e2']
hash = {'e1' => 5, 'e8' => 8}

it "Include any element from elements" do
  hash.should include('e1') || hash.should include('e2')
end
```

hash should include any element(as key) from elements. there is a more elegant way?. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
(elements & hash.keys).should_not be_blank
```

This would pass if the array contains at least one element which is present in another_array.

`hash.keys` simply return an array of all keys of that hash.

Comment: Sorry, I had not drafted correctly my question, so it not works.

Comment: Updated the answer for the hash keys.

Comment: `be_empty` is better since it doesn’t rely on ActiveSupport’s `blank?`. Plus the return value will always be an array anyway.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Definitely. This would be essential especially when we are writing rspecs for a general ruby program rather than a Rails app.

Answer (score 1):

Probably:

```
anotherArray = anotherArray | elements
```

Or simply

```
anotherArray |= elements
```

For the update:

```
elements.each{|e| hash[e] = e[1..-1].to_i unless hash.has_key?(e)}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had not drafted correctly my question, so it not works.

Comment: Which one does `it` refers to, `hash` or `anotherArray`?